# Asynchronous .NET sockets & standard sockets using select(): Why does select() prevent the async callbacks from happening?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, c++-cli, winsock

I have an application written in C++/CLI that uses a library written in C#.  The application was written using standard socket APIs and uses select() to multiplex a bunch of ordinary non-async sockets.  However, the third party library uses .NET sockets and uses the asynchronous results and callbacks.

Here's the scenario:  I create a bunch of regular sockets in the main thread (a C++/CLI application that uses mostly native-style code).  I create the third party library vendor's C# "session" object which, internally, has a bunch of asynchronous sockets from the .NET classes.

What I noticed was that if I put a NULL timeout parameter into select() in the main thread in which I instantiate the C# "session" object, that no asynchronous callbacks are made at all for their .NET sockets.  If I use a time-out of, say, 1-second, and no other activity happens on my non-async sockets, then no async-socket callbacks are delivered until select() times out.

Somehow, select() is preventing the callbacks to happen for the .NET sockets.  How do I avoid this?  Is there some alternative polling method I can use for the old sockets that would still allow the .NET sockets to have their asynchronous callbacks delivered?

Comment: I imagine that the callbacks happen on the same thread, so if Select() is blocking that thread it is unable to process anything else in the run loop.

Comment: The part that I find confusing is that the MSDN help for select() says that when it's blocking, that it's in an alertable wait-state.  Do .NET async callbacks not count as something that would cause an "alert" ?

Comment: I believe all of the .Net callbacks are processed in Application.DoEvents() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx

Comment: I don't use a windows form at all; it's a console application.  This function you linked appears to be in the forms namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

In AsyncCallbacks used in .NET, you cannot have any functions that block at all, including send()/recv() functions -- even if they are non-blocking[1] (at least according to my own tests.)  When a blocking function is called in an AsyncCallback, the behavior is undefined.  Once I got rid of this "undefinedness" from the code, things started working as normal.

I re-templatized my classes by writing some policy classes that swapped out select() for WaitForMultipleObjectsEx() and solved the issue by putting a SetEvent() in the AsyncCallback to trigger the multiplexing.  This seemed to solve most of the issues.

[1] Edit:  See below comment.  Whether I used send() on a non-blocking or blocking socket didn't seem to make a difference with regards to "breaking things" and going into undefined behaviors.

Comment: Oh, what I meant to say was that if you make send()/recv() non-blocking and use them in an async callback, it still "counts".  When I cut out the send() on a non-blocking socket in the async callback, things started working.  Switching the blocking/non-blocking status of the socket used in send() didn't seem to make a difference.  Edited the above response.